# How can two VitualBox have the same IP

Tags: virtualbox, clone

I cloned my VitualBox which is running Win-XP. My orignal VBOX and the cloned one both are running on the same IPAdr. This is the strangest thing i have ever seen. How is this possible.

How can the network assign the same IPAdr to both VBOX?

I have cloned before but didn't have this issue... Can it be something to do with macAdr?

Comment: Check the mac adress in a cmd with ipconfig /all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be using NAT network mode. Check it or use the bridged mode if you want to have them separately.

In it's not the case, please provide more information, so we can help you!

UPDATE: it's bridged mode, so the problem is elsewhere. With a screenshot of the network configuration screen would be easier to find some reasons...

Comment: thx for answer: I have bridged mode running on both VBOX. This doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: And I assume MACs are different, right? Otherwise, this could explain duplicated IP with certain nasty DHCP servers.

Comment: They are running on same MAC. Under network configuration TCP/IP I was able to manually set IPAdr. and it works. But that doesn't help me understand why it did that in first place.

Comment: The DHCP server might be configured to assign the same IP to that MAC. This is a good configuration in certain cases (for instance, when the VM2 is designed to take VM1's place in case of failure), but it can be a problem in other situations.

Comment: True that, I understand why DHCP server is assigning the same IPAdr to both VBOX, but its still very unclear why it didn't happen before..